# How to run a php script as cron task and move by steps (?id=1) then (?id=2)

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

I want to run a script by id / steps because my script is too heavy. so i want to chunk it into some small parts and then run them automatically.
example:
first run part 1 ?id=1, after finishing it should load ?id=2 and so on
how can i do it automatically?
I cant use HTML?!

Comment: not clear why it can't just be one file called by cron. perhaps a script that uses include\require for the other scripts.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What have you tried? Also, if you're running via cron (CLI) there is no "query string" per se. You have an argument array that is passed to your script. This is stored in the superglobals $argv and $argc unless your server configuration has it turned off (not sure if it can be for CLI tho).

One way would be to record which step is complete when it is complete in a text file or database. When you run the script again, see which step you last completed and perform the next one, etc.

Comment: i can use argv , but you know because the run time of this script is so long the server doesnt let me do that, so i wanted to do it in steps but automatic steps to reduce the run time